# How chained static_cast is well-defined?

Tags: c++, static-cast

> (5.2.9/10) An rvalue of type "pointer to cv1 void" can be converted to an rvalue of type "pointer to cv2 T," where T is an object type and cv2
>   is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than,
>   cv1. A value of type pointer to object converted to "pointer to cv
>   void" and back to the **original pointer type** will have its original
>   value.

Since, the result of casting from `void*` has be `int*` (original pointer type) so, what makes the following cast valid?

```
int i = 10;
double *pd_2 = static_cast<double*>(static_cast<void*>(&i));
```

Comment: That cast **isn't** well-defined.

Comment: I thought casting from `void*` is implementation defined

Comment: No, but it seems like undefined behavior to me.

Answer (score 2):

That cast **isn't** well-defined.

Comment: I think that leaves us with implementation-defined and undefined-behavior. Or is it just roughly considered "ok" to do so?

Comment: @user1086635: I can't remember which it is.  But either way, you probably shouldn't be writing code that does this.

Comment: Casting should be ok, it's just that attempting to deref pd_2 is going to UB, since it's not really a double pd_2 is pointing it.

Comment: @Oli: Anyway, I'll accept this as answer after you come back with it. ;)